# What is the (condition) ? val1 : val2 statement called?

Tags: swift, logical-operators

I am working on a project and need to know what the name of the statement if officially called. I have used it a lot, I just no clue what the name is.

Example statement:

```
let x = didJump ? 10 : 5
```

Answer (score 2):

The question mark is called thé "ternairy operator". The statement is called a "ternairy statement".

Comment: The question mark by itself is merely a token. Together with the colon, it forms the *ternary conditional operator*. It can form other operators, such as the postfix `?` operator to make an *optional-chaining expression*. *The Swift Programming Language* classifies statements as simple statements, compiler control statements, and control flow statements. This is a simple statement. The book does not classify statements particularly as ternary statements; this is merely an instance of an expression used to form a simple statement.

Answer (score 1):

It is called the *ternary conditional operator* in *The Swift Programming Language (Swift 5.0)*.